# Using System.getProperty as a condition

Tags: java, system, getproperty

Is it OK to use xxx.equals(System.getProperty(key)) as a condition? Or Am I supposed to use the properties for some other purposes?

I have been reading these;

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

however, I'm a little confused on its usage. 
Some more links or some code samples would be very helpful.

Thank you...

Comment: I don't see why not...it's entirely up to you what you want to do with the retrieved value, and performing a simple comparison is perfectly legit.

Comment: you can use them for whatever purpose they are useful to your application. It IS OK to use them in conditional statements. (just make sure you are either handling nulls or are using the overloaded getProperty(key, default))

Comment: @amol the form in the OP is already null safe.

Comment: @Mehmet Yesin, if you have found your answer accept the one that helped you the most so others can learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everybody said yes you can do this.

Regarding:

> however, I'm a little confused on its usage. Some more links or some
>   code samples would be very helpful.

try this [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0150.html), you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's ok you use them. (example: `os.name` to figure out what operation system)

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's OK.  Whether it's true will obviously depend on the value in `xxx` though.

Answer (score 2):

I think that when you really need you can use it :)